# Oracle select random rows from table based on criteria in another table (Stratified Sampling)

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I have 2 tables. The first is the base table with the information in it and the 2nd table has the criteria I need random rows selected from Table 1 based on criteria in Table 2. Would prefer not doing this manually since the permutations for the criteria in my table is close to hundred. Need the code to get try get random stratified samples from my database.

**Table_1**

```
   ID          Fruit       Subject 
   123       Apple      Math
   124       Apple      Science  
   125       Apple      History  
   126       Apple      Math  
   127       Apple      Science  
   128       Orange     Math  
   129       Orange     Science  
   130       Orange     Science  
   131       Orange     Science  
   132       Orange     History  
   133       Orange     Science  
   134       Pineapple  History  
   135       Pineapple  History  
   136       Pineapple  History  
   137       Pineapple  History  
   138       Pineapple  Math
```

**Table_2**

```
   Fruit      Subject   Count
   Apple        Math        1
   Apple        Science     2
   Apple        History     1
   Orange       Science     2
   Orange       History     1
   Pineapple    History     3
   Pineapple    Math        1
```

**Output (Random Selection based on criteria in Table 2)**

```
   ID         Fruit       Subject 
   123      Apple       Math
   124      Apple       Science
   125      Apple       History
   127      Apple       Science
   128      Orange      Math
   129      Orange      Science
   130      Orange      Science
   132      Orange      History
   134      Pineapple   History
   135      Pineapple   History
   137      Pineapple   History
   138      Pineapple   Math
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what criteria are you talking about? If all you need is random rows, then just join the tables and apply **ROWNUM** in the filter predicate and you will get random rows.

Comment: Table 2 has the criteria. So taking the **1st** row in Table 2, what I need is **1** random sample from Table 1 with Apple in Fruit and Math in Subject. For row **2** it would be **2** random samples from Table 2 with Apple in Fruit and Science in Subject. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you can sort the rows using `dbms_random` and use the analytic function `row_number` to sort them within the partition

```
select id,
       fruit,
       subject
  from(select t1.*,
              t2.cnt,
              row_number() over (partition by t1.fruit, t1.subject
                                     order by dbms_random.value) rnk
         from table_1 t1
              join table_2 t2
                on( t1.fruit   = t2.fruit and
                    t1.subject = t2.subject ))
 where rnk <= cnt
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you Justin!!